# error with linux-based mailserver

Tags: mail-server

i got the following problem with my myserver based on Linux Debian 8:

i´m unable to send the test-mail via roundcube , it Returns the error : not ok
and i´m also unable to do the test-Login via roundcube , it Returns the error
Login failed for admin@mydomain from *** Unable to send command: A0002 LOGIN admin@mydomain

i also tryed to re-install it  but it wont work

can somneone help me with this ?

Comment: Bitte, schreiben Sie die Frage auf Englisch.

Comment: have edited it :)